# ios passing data to MBProgressHUD ending with strange crash

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com, mbprogresshud

I apologize at the very start for this long winded question.

In my App I download big video files (30-60Mb). I obviously want to tell the user about the progress. The download is from Urban Airship and I use one of their methods to obtain the progress.  However this happens in a TableViewController but the download indicator (MBProgressHUD) starts from another view, call it UADetail.

To pass the progress from one view to the other I use a Singleton.  Randomly, it can happen early, late or not at all, the App crashes with this in the log;

> 2012-03-12 15:13:30.528 isengua-en[3478:681f] HUD lessonDownloadProgress: 0.053478
>   2012-03-12 15:13:30.553 isengua-en[3478:707] Lessonlist progress: 0.055272
>   2012-03-12 15:13:30.562 isengua-en[3478:707] LLVC downHUD progress: 0.055272
>   2012-03-12 15:13:30.565 isengua-en[3478:707] -[LessonListViewController >productsDownloadProgress:count:] [Line 57] [StoreFrontDelegate] productsDownloadProgress: 0.055272 count: 1
>   2012-03-12 15:13:30.569 isengua-en[3478:6307] *** -[CFNumber _getValue:forType:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x83c6e80

**First is the LessonListViewController;**

```
- (void)productsDownloadProgress:(float)progress count:(int)count 
{
    DataManager *sharedManager = [DataManager sharedManager];
    sharedManager.downHUD = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress];
    NSLog(@"Lessonlist progress: %f", progress);
    NSLog(@"LLVC downHUD progress: %f", [sharedManager.downHUD floatValue]);
    UALOG(@"[StoreFrontDelegate] productsDownloadProgress: %f count: %d", progress, count);
    if (count == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Downloads complete in LessonListView!");
    }
```

}

**The Singleton looks like this;**

```
@implementation DataManager

@synthesize downHUD;




+ (DataManager *)sharedManager
{
    static DataManager *sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        sharedManager = [[self alloc] init]; 
    });
    return sharedManager;

}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        downHUD = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)0];
    }
    return self;
}


 - (void)dealloc {
 // Should never be called, but just here for clarity really.
     NSLog(@"dealloc called in DataManager");
 }



@end
```

**And it then get read in the UADetail;**

```
- (void)showWithLabelDeterminate {

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view]; 
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];


    // Set determinate mode
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Waiting","");

    // myProgressTask uses the HUD instance to update progress
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(lessonDownloadProgress) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}


-(void)lessonDownloadProgress
{
    DataManager *sharedManager = [DataManager sharedManager];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
    HUD.progress = [sharedManager.downHUD floatValue];
    HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"DownLoading","");

    while (HUD.progress < 1)
    {
        [self parentViewController];
        NSLog(@"HUD lessonDownloadProgress: %f", HUD.progress);
        HUD.progress = [sharedManager.downHUD floatValue];                       
        NSString *percent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", HUD.progress/1*100];
        HUD.detailsLabelText = [percent stringByAppendingString:@"%"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to this myself.
After putting in a usleep(50000) inside the while loops it stopped.
Maybe the loop was running too fast and checking the sharedManager.downHUD too often, interfering with the writing to it from the other class.